# Query the org agenda from the commandline?

Tags: org-mode

I'd like to display event counts in a conky window. Things like tasks scheduled for today, within the next 3 days, 15 days, count of pending todo items, etc. Since conky doesn't "talk" org-mode, the next best way is to call a shell script and use its output.

Can I call emacs in batch mode for this? Is there an org-agenda function that prints event counts? Should I do my own parsing instead?

Comment: I am unaware of a built-in counting function.  If all you need is the raw data that goes into an agenda buffer, the following example can be used to extract that data normally created with the `org-agenda-list` function.  The example creates a buffer for displaying purposes, but that step can be eliminated and the parsing/counting can be done with just the list -- without actually creating a display buffer.  The org-agenda-files are opened/accessed/queried during this process.  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/12563/2287  This process could be done in batch mode, though I've never tried it.

Comment: The last section of the example in the following link demonstrates how to query/use the text-properties within the list of raw data -- http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17903/2287 -- the relevant section is labeled `BEGIN modification` through to `END modification`.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of org logic is bound up in large functions (i.e. org-agenda-list), so you probably need to write your own functions with a bunch of duplicated logic.  `org-map-entries` might be a useful starting point for you (use the `'agenda` scope).  You can work out match patterns (http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html) over scheduled or deadline dates for your counting conditions and simply look at the length of the returned list or do aggregation within your map function using `org-get-deadline-time` and other functions.

I would suggest invoking `emacs --batch --script ~/.emacs.d/init.el --eval "(prin1 (my-counting-function))"` and examine only stdout.  Replace with your own init location (since it otherwise would not be loaded in batch mode).

An example count of headings scheduled today:

```
(length (org-map-entries nil "SCHEDULED=\"<today>\"" 'agenda))
```

Comment: The only point in calling emacs would be if org already shipped with useful functions for my purposes. Emacs being rather heavy, even in batch mode, I will probably write my own lightweight parsing in something else. I will leave the question open for now.