# Can you configure the agenda weekly view to display horizontally?

Tags: org-mode

When displaying the weekly agenda, can days be displayed side by side, the way they are displayed in Google Calendar's weekly view?

Comment: Without creating a custom version of `org-agenda`, I do not believe that this is possible.  Your best option will be to incorporate `calfw` (which supports `org-mode` tasks/events):  https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-calfw -- it offers month view, week view, two-week view, and day view.  If you are interested in creating your own `org-agenda` view, the following link has an example of how to extract the data using the same method as `calfw`:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/12563/2287  See issue 61 for certain proposed bug fixes to `calfw`:  https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-calfw/issues/61