# Org-mode calendar integration?

Tags: org-mode, calendar

Calendar (invoked by <kbd>M-x calendar</kbd>) has diary integration feature.
By this, one can view any special date on the calendar buffer (the day will be colored if there is diary entry for that day),
and view the day's detailed entry by <kbd>d</kbd>.

Since org-mode also has feature of timestamp, integrating it to the calendar, just like the diary entry, would be nice.
It doesn't necessarily be integration with `calendar`, but somthing that enables view of dates as in calendar format and then open the detailed date view from that calendar.

Question: is there such feature?

Comment: You may want to have a look at emacs-calfw (https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-calfw).

Comment: A new library can be created using (in part) the function `org-get-entries-fn` in the link of the following thread to obtain a list of all SCHEDULED items for the period displayed on the 3-month/12-month calendar.  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/12563/2287  The function `calendar-mark-visible-date` can be used to color the 3-month/12-month calendar with entries for SCHEDULED, birthdays, holidays, diary, etc.  If at some point in the future I decide to make my in-house library public, I may revisit this thread.  The culture of stackexchange does not favor posting entire libraries as answers.

Comment: Alternatively, the function `calendar-cursor-to-nearest-date` or `org-read-date` can be used to extract a date from the calendar and an `*Org Agenda*` buffer can be created for a specific date -- e.g., `org-agenda-list` with the appropriate setting of exiting variables.

Comment: You may want to checkout [org-journal](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OrgJournal), which might partially fulfill your needs. Though I haven't used it personally.

Answer (score 2):

When in org-agenda, you can press `c` to open a Calendar on the date at point. In a calendar, you can press `c` to open org-agenda on the date at point.

Comment: and vice versa with `(setq org-agenda-include-diary t)` you'll see diary entries in the org-agenda.