# Extracting TODO items from .org file for display

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I'd like to extract open TODO items from my agenda so I can display them somewhere prominent. I'm thinking maybe Conky and put it on the desktop, or put a TODO counter on my task bar, something like that.

What are my options? Are there any useable parsers outside of Emacs? Has someone come up with a fancy incantation of grep?

Comment: To extract just the raw data of what one normally sees when calling `M-x org-agenda-list`, see:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/12563/2287 -- that can be used to create all sorts of goodies, including exporting the list.  `org-toodledo.el` needs some TLC to make it a little more compatible with the current API:  https://github.com/christopherjwhite/org-toodledo .  I use a custom version (with all Toodledo recognized priorities and keywords, and ...) that works just fine for my personal needs.  There are taskbar apps and desktop apps and mobile device apps that synchronize with Toodledo.

Comment: FYI:  Emacs can do a `batch` run to gather the tasks/events -- e.g., `(org-get-entries-fn '(6 1 2015) '(12 31 2020))` -- thus eliminating the need for other tools such as `grep`, etc.  This is true even if another instance of Emacs is already open.