# Yearly calendar view of agenda (with colored background)

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, calendar

I would like to have a yearly calendar view of my agenda. The code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547912/emacs-calendar-show-more-than-3-months shows how to display a calendar for the whole year. Ideally, I would like to connect it to my agenda such as to color the background of each day according to the number of events for this day. This would allow me to quickly visually check what are the busy days (I imagine I can probably query the information but I would prefer such a visual). Is there any package that could do that?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, I am the only one who has written a proof concept of how this could be implemented.  However, I haven't updated it in years and it would need some tweaking to make it compatible with a current version of org-mode.  I use a slightly modified version of this in my own custom-setup, but the draft on Github is fairly similar (albiet a little older): https://github.com/lawlist/lorg-calendar  I am also the one who wrote-up one of answers in the thread linked in the question above; i.e., a 12-month rotating calendar.  FYI, the `calfw` library has 1-month, 2-weeks, 1-week, 1-day.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was afraid of having missed an obvious option or package for doing this. From your message, I guess I'll have to try to do is myself.

Comment: Here is a link demonstrating how to extract the raw data used to compile the agenda buffer https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/12563/2287 The raw data can be parsed and the information needed to populate the `lorg-calendar` can be obtained with a little bit of work.  A working draft would probably only take a couple of hours, assuming you are aware of text-properties contained within the raw data and so forth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up doing it in Python and I display it in the terminal.
Code at https://gist.github.com/rougier/d559fbd766da14540e8eb47435a5782d

[image: Result]