# Color calendar day according to number of event in org-agenda

Tags: org-agenda, highlighting, calendar

I would like to color the background of each day in calendar according to the number of events in my org-agenda. The idea is to have a quick and visual idea of what are the busiest days. The code from [How to highlight weekend days in Emacs calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008106/how-to-highlight-weekend-days-in-emacs-calendar)? might be a good start and I would need to write a function that, given a date, returns the number of scheduled event from my org-agenda/diary (I use org-diary) and set the face to `face-busy-0`, `face-busy-1`, etc.

I already wrote a Python code for doing more or less the same in the terminal (see [Yearly calendar view of agenda (with colored background)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/54648/yearly-calendar-view-of-agenda-with-colored-background) but my elisp is not so good.

Comment: I actually do exactly as you describe, but it is a little complex and requires a custom solution.  For some ideas, you may wish to check out my example repository for `lorg-calendar` which includes some highlighting onto a 3-month or 12-month calendar for certain events:  https://github.com/lawlist/lorg-calendar  And, as I mentioned in one of my previous comments to a thread you linked in the question above, one idea is to extract the data that is used to create the org-agenda and operate on that extracted data to generate the calendar view:https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/12563/2287

Comment: In the `lorg-calendar` repository example linked in the previous comment, I use a modified version of a `mark-visible-calendar-date` by Drew Adams in his `calendar+.el` library:  https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/calendar%2B.el  That library may have some other goodies that could help you on your quest.

Comment: Thanks for all the pointers, I'll start with that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up with the code below. I guess it can be shorten/optimized (it's a bit slow) but it does the job.

```
(defface busy-1  '((t :foreground "black" :background "#eceff1")) "")
(defface busy-2  '((t :foreground "black" :background "#cfd8dc")) "")
(defface busy-3  '((t :foreground "black" :background "#b0bec5")) "")
(defface busy-4  '((t :foreground "black" :background "#90a4ae")) "")
(defface busy-5  '((t :foreground "white" :background "#78909c")) "")
(defface busy-6  '((t :foreground "white" :background "#607d8b")) "")
(defface busy-7  '((t :foreground "white" :background "#546e7a")) "")
(defface busy-8  '((t :foreground "white" :background "#455a64")) "")
(defface busy-9  '((t :foreground "white" :background "#37474f")) "")
(defface busy-10 '((t :foreground "white" :background "#263238")) "")

(defadvice calendar-generate-month
  (after highlight-weekend-days (month year indent) activate)
  "Highlight weekend days"
  (dotimes (i 31)
    (let ((date (list month (1+ i) year))
          (count (length (org-agenda-get-day-entries
                          "~/Documents/org/agenda.org" (list month (1+ i) year)))))
      (cond ((= count 0) ())
            ((= count 1) (calendar-mark-visible-date date 'busy-1))
            ((= count 2) (calendar-mark-visible-date date 'busy-2))
            ((= count 3) (calendar-mark-visible-date date 'busy-3))
            ((= count 4) (calendar-mark-visible-date date 'busy-4))
            ((= count 5) (calendar-mark-visible-date date 'busy-5))
            ((= count 6) (calendar-mark-visible-date date 'busy-6))
            ((= count 7) (calendar-mark-visible-date date 'busy-7))
            ((= count 8) (calendar-mark-visible-date date 'busy-8))
            ((= count 9) (calendar-mark-visible-date date 'busy-9))
            (t  (calendar-mark-visible-date date 'busy-10)))
)))
```

[image]