# Copying Column View (Org-Mode)

Tags: org-mode, column

Is there a way to copy the table presented in "column view" as raw text?

Comment: I have not played with `column-view` using a variation of the code in the following link, but the code "as is" extracts the raw data used to create a standard `*Org Agenda*` buffer based upon the let-bound settings of the code:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/12563/2287  I have not tried out the code with recent versions of `org-mode`, but I would imagine the same principle will still work.  Perhaps you can adapt that to suit your needs to extract the text that would otherwise go into a `column-view`.  The raw data will contain `text-properties` (with more data) that can also be extracted.

Comment: See [Capturing column view](https://orgmode.org/manual/Capturing-column-view.html#Capturing-column-view) in the Org mode manual.

Comment: There is also [overlaysToText](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OverlaysToText), but its implementation does not seem to be very robust. The output buffer looks a bit different than the input buffer.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, you should look at the [Capturing column view](https://orgmode.org/manual/Capturing-column-view.html#Capturing-column-view) section of the Org manual for additional details, but doing

```
M-x org-insert-columns-dblock RET global RET
```

should give you a good beginning.

E.g. given this file:

```
 TODO foo

foo

* TODO bar
  :LOGBOOK:
  CLOCK: [2020-03-05 Thu 07:44]
  :END:

bar
```

if you position the cursor at the end of the file and do `M-x org-insert-columns-dblock RET global RET` you will get this:

```
* TODO foo

foo

* TODO bar
  :LOGBOOK:
  CLOCK: [2020-03-05 Thu 07:44]
  :END:

bar

#+BEGIN: columnview :hlines 1 :id global
| ITEM | TODO | PRIORITY | TAGS |
|------+------+----------+------|
| foo  | TODO | B        |      |
|------+------+----------+------|
| bar  | TODO | B        |      |
#+END:
```

If you then change the file (e.g. add another heading), you can update the dynamic block with `M-x org-update-dblock` or just `C-c C-c` on the `#+BEGIN:` line of the block.